# Calling a web service operation gives 500 and 400 error

Tags: c#, iis, wsdl

I am getting 500 error in IIS logs and 400 bad request in other logs when I call a service operation. Is this because of WSDL mismatch?

Can someone please give the direction in which I should start looking into this issue and what else I should check?

Comment: Check your Application and System Event Log for more details. With the information provided there's no way to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Use Fiddler or something to look at the response from the server. Servers sometimes include a message (possibly in HTML) to tell you what went wrong.